# после срабатывания catch выходит из программы

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
void program1 ()
{
    unsigned int a, b, s;
    std::cout << "\nThe program for adding two natural numbers.\nEnter terms separated by spaces: ";
    try
    {
        std::cin >> a >> b;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "\nInput error!!!";
        return;
    }
    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "\nInput error!!!";
        return;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum = " << a + b;
}
int main()
{
    bool answer;
    program1();
    std::cout << "\nOne more? (1 - yes, 0 - no): ";
    std::cin >> answer;
    if (answer)
    {
        main();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

когда срабатывает catch (например, вводятся буквы), программа выводит `One more? (1 - yes, 0 - no):`, но не ждет ввода `std::cin >> answer;`. подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Comment: Приводите код, ввод, вывод и ожидаемый вывод программы **полностью**. Приведенная программа не собирается, а если даже пофиксить инклюды и прочее, то `catch` все равно никогда не будет срабатывать.

Comment: отсутствует только строчка с подключением iostream. catch нужен чтобы избежать обработки введенных "не чисел".

Comment: `catch` тут бесполезен, так как внутри `try` не выбрасываются никакие исключения. При этом утверждается, что он якобы срабатывает. Так что в вопросе либо приведен не настойщий код, либо не настоящее описание.

Comment: Не принято добавлять решение в сам вопрос. Напишите ответ ниже, и тыкните галочку на нем, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда срабатывает `catch` (а вот срабатывает ли он у вас? мне кажется, что вылетаете вы по второму признаку, `if (a == 0 || b == 0)`, просто считаете, что это исключение... а на самом деле никакого исключения нет), у вас явно `cin` в состоянии `fail`, так что в строке `std::cin >> answer;` просто ничего не читается (из потока в состоянии fail), и вы вылетаете из программы.

И, кстати, `main()` рекурсивно вызывать — очень плохо пахнет... Я бы делал так:

```
void program1 ()
{
    unsigned int a, b, s;
    std::cout << "\nThe program for adding two natural numbers.\nEnter terms separated by spaces: ";
    if (!(std::cin >> a >> b))
    {
        std::cout << "\nInput error!!!";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else std::cout << "Sum = " << a + b;
}
int main()
{
    for(int answer = 1; answer;)
    {
        program1();
        std::cout << "\nOne more? (1 - yes, 0 - no): ";
        std::cin >> answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за наводку на fail